# queryIntentActivities on Android Marshmallow and above

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to get all apps that can open specific url. for example: facebook for urls with "Facebook" or Linkedin for urls with "linkedin".

The code works fine with "queryIntentActivities" before android version marshmallow. On marshmallow it works only for specific scheme, but i can't query for url.
My code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http");
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(builder.build());
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
```